# How to check a time present between Two time 10 AM and 10 PM in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to check a time present between Two time 10 AM and 10 PM in rails?

Comment: If you use `Date.js` then `if (ur_time > Date.parseExact("10:00 AM", "hh:mm tt") && ur_time < Date.parseExact("10:00 PM", "hh:mm tt"))
{
   alert("Success")
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 (10...22) === DateTime.now.hour
```

Comment: `(10...22).include? DateTime.now.hour` will also work, and is a bit more readable

Comment: That will return true for eg "22:59", which should return false according to the question requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Set some example values

```
hr1 = 10.hours
hr2 = 22.hours
mytime = Time.now
```

Do the test

```
if (hr1..hr2).include?(mytime - mytime.beginning_of_day)
  #it's between hr1 and hr2
end
```